# HTTP ERROR 500. Localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache

estoy teniendo problemas al desplegar una mini aplicacion de prueba en mi ubuntu.

La aplicacion simplemente es una pagina en la que puedes logearte o registrarte, si no estas logueado te registras y luego te logueas y te lleva a una pagina de bienvenida, facil. El problema esta en que en windows usando wamp me funciona perfectamente, pero en ubuntu, usando el paquete lamp, me deja llegar a la primera pagina:

[image: Primera pagina]

Pero luego, le de a lo que le de me salta el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

He leido mil foros diciendo que puede ser un error de permisos, le he puesto a todos los archivos permisos 777 (Aun sabiendo que no es bueno, solo por probar, por desesperacion) y no funciona, he cambiado unas directivas del servidor para que muestre un log de errores y tampoco, he probado de todo y no hay manera de que funcione,y no es problema del codigo ya que en windows con el wamp como digo funciona perfectamente.

Alguien podria ayudarme?

Edito:

El compañero Francisco-garrido tiene razon, se me ha olvidado poner el log:

> *Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/common/Medoo.php:309 
> Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/modelo/exec/login.php(52): Medoo->openConnection(Array) #1 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/modelo/form/registro/mdlRegistro.php(48): Login::duplicateUsuario(NULL) #2 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/controlador/EventDispatcher.php(21): mdlRegistro->onGestionPagina(Array) #3 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/controlador/controlador.php(13): EventDispatcher->trigger('onGestionPagina') #4 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/controlador/controlador.php(9): Controlador::_gestionPagina() #5 /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/index.php(11): Controlador::init() #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Proyectos/TFG/mvc/common/Medoo.php on line 309*

Edito 2:

Vale, ya esta, el problema era el usuario con el que estaba realizando la conexion a la base de datos en la configuracion, que estaba usando root y sin password porque es un trabajo que tengo que entregar y asi me han pedido que sea, cambiando el usuario ha funcionado, pero el problema es que el usuario tiene que ser root y sin contraseña, ya que ademas en mysql te deja entrar de esa manera, sabeis como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Error 500, si no sabemos de donde viene poco te podemos ayudar. ¿Que dicen los logs?

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido tienes razon, ya esta editado

Comment: Asegurate de que tienes bien configurada la conexion a la base de datos, pero viendo que intentas entrar con root en un servidor lamp...

Comment: Vale, ya esta, el problema era el usuario con el que estaba realizando la conexion a la base de datos en la configuracion, que estaba usando root y sin password porque es un trabajo que tengo que entregar y asi me han pedido que sea, cambiando el usuario ha funcionado, pero el problema es que el usuario tiene que ser root y sin contraseña, ya que ademas en mysql te deja entrar de esa manera, sabeis como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Lo dice claramente al principio del log de error: *Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in...* **este mensaje aparece cuando hay un problema con las credenciales de acceso a la base de datos**.

Comment: "pero el problema es que el usuario tiene que ser root y sin contraseña" ... nos explicas mejor ese requerimiento??

Comment: El problema es de la persona que te pidió ese requerimiento. Aunque sea una tarea o lo que sea, es una vulnerabilidad gravísima que se está incentivando a hacer, sin contar el hecho de que te ha dado más problemas que el facilitarte las cosas. Considera hablar con la persona que te pidió eso, porque según mi opinión no tiene ningún sentido, cuando perfectamente podrías entregar usuario-contraseña a quien te haya solicitado eso para que pueda acceder a tu BD.