# This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos como pueden ver tengo este error generado en mi pagina **php**  desde ubuntu:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Y no hize esta pregunta sin antes investigar en distintos lugares como [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243190/http-error-500-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request) y algunos videos de yt, el problema es que ninguna solucuión funciono y no se que hacer, por cierto quiero aclarar de que solo pasa cuando me conecto a una base de datos y este es el codigo que hice para la conexión:

```
<?php

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'nombre', 'contraseña', 'database');

if($mysql)
{
$mysql->query('SELECT * FROM testmysql WHERE content="Conexión establecida 
correctamente"');
}
else
{

}

?>
```

Y si tengo todos los datos de inicio de sesión en mysql escritos correctamente, espero me puedan ayudar. Desde ya gracias :) (por cierto si me falta mas información por dar acerca de lo tengo o he hecho díganme y con gusto la añadiré).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifica tu archivo con estas lineas

```php7
#Determina si los errores deberían ser impresos en pantalla 
#como parte de la salida o si deberían ocultarse al usuario.
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

#Establece cuales errores son notificados
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Para que quede de esta forma

```php7
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'nombre', 'contraseña', 'database');

if($mysql){
    $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM testmysql WHERE content="Conexión establecida 
    correctamente"');
}else{}


?>
```

Esto hace que te muestre los errores en pantalla con más detalle. Por ejemplo a mi me arroja este

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/fecha.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/fecha.php on line 6

Mi error surge porque no tengo instalado el paquete de `php7.4-mysql`.

Para comprobar si está instalado el paquete mysql de tu versión de php, corre este comando

```sh
$ apt list --installed | grep ^php
```

Esta instrucción lista los paquetes instalados en tu equipo y filtra aquellos que inicien con **php**

```sh
php-common/hirsute,hirsute,now 2:76ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
php7.4-cli/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.4-common/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.4-json/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.4-opcache/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.4-readline/hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
php7.4/hirsute-updates,hirsute-updates,hirsute-security,hirsute-security,now 7.4.16-1ubuntu2.1 all [installed]
```

Si no te aparece en la lista ningún paquete que diga *mysql* debes de installarlo. El nombre del paquete puede cambiar según tu versión de php

```shell
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql
```

Después de instalarlo necesitas reiniciar el servidor `apache`

```shell
systemctl restart apache2
```

## Nota

Usa los `display_errors` y `error_reporting(E_ALL)` en fase de desarrollo,

Te recomiendo usar un archivo php con estas tres lineas de código para que solo tengas que modificar este archivo al pasar a producción.
Quedaría algo así:

### Producción

errores.php

```php7
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

### Desarrollo

errores.php

```php7
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

### Incluyes errores.php en los demás archivos

```php7
<?php

include '/ruta/errores.php' #<-Aquí lo incluyes

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'nombre', 'contraseña', 'database');

if($mysql){
    $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM testmysql WHERE content="Conexión establecida 
    correctamente"');
}else{}


?>
```

Comment: O simplemente haces `include` en desarrollo y cuando pasas a producción comentas el `include`. ;)

Comment: @MauricioContreras sip, es mas fácil quitar el include de 20 archivos que modificando un solo archivo :)

Comment: @alejandro00 probé con el código que pusiste en la parte de desarrollo y justo me sale que no encontró `mysqli`, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: @Davidflogar ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: @alejandro00 gracias al parecer no tenia descargado mysql, ese era el problema